# How to minimize open windows by a click?

Tags: 16.04, taskbar

To minimize all the open windows, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Is there an *icon like stuff* that I could drag and drop to the taskbar as a click is quicker and easier for me than a 3 simultaneous buttons press?

Comment: Int UBUNTU 18.04 LTS,  `Ctrl + D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the *System Settings* program, go to *Appearance*, go to the *Behavior* tab, and click on *Add show desktop icon to the launcher*.

*Show Desktop* will then be added to the dash. Clicking on it will hide all windows. Clicking on it again will unhide them.

Comment: +1 but just one addition: this action is called *minimizing* all windows. I include this term here to make it easier for later visitors to find this answer.